# How to crop a big image in Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

how can I crop image in Bootstrap carousel if the resolution exceed the carousel size?

I've try using this CSS but it don't crop the image1 which is a little bigger than image2 and image2.

```
.carousel{width:640px; height:360px;}
```

[***DEMO: jsbin.com/hux/1***](http://jsbin.com/hux/1)

I want the image1 to be cropped like this:

[image]

[***DEMO: jsbin.com/hux/1***](http://jsbin.com/hux/1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add overflow:hidden to the carousel class

`.carousel {overflow:hidden}`

Comment: Is there a way to scall the carousel without any distorsion on image?

Comment: you need to set the carousel width as a percentage. Because you've set the images themselves with a max-width of 100%, they should scale accordingly. Alternatively, you could use one transparent gif as the image for all your slides, and apply these blue circle images as background images and use the background-size property to scale the images.

Comment: @partypete25 Ok but how to show the entire image instead of hide it ?

Comment: @Zl3n that's very vague. Set overflow to visible? Change your img max width to none? Have you got some code you can show me?